# Add flag if description field is not empty

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

If you add any information to the description field of a google calendar (web) entry, it would be very useful to see a flag/mark/asterisk in the subject line. Then you can easily scroll through your event list or overview without double-clicking all records for (non-existent) details.

Is there an addon/plugin that will do this for me? Or do I have to program a chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Calendars:get`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) by using this request, you were able to detect if the description of the calendar is empty or not.

Here's a sample request:

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId
```

Use `calendarId` to retrieve calendar IDs, call the `calendarList.list` method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the `primary` keyword.

Note that every request, your application sends to the Google Calendar API. Your request must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests.

Successful `Response` include description as string:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendar",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  "timeZone": string
}
```